# How to download a file in a remote server using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, download, remote-access

I have been searching the internet as well as many posts from SO and had no luck. I have the following code to get a file from a remote server.

```
$url  = 'http://www.example.com/images/abc.png';
$path = '/home/axxxxxxx/public_html/images/abc.png';

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

`$url` and `$path` represent a file from one server. When I run the code, the html page outputs a strange code which starts with **`‰PNG  IHDRàw=ø IDATxÚ•yLWÇ¿3³3³ì² (VP)àUÓzDc«`**....

When I opened the new.png using a text editor, the code I got was identical to the code in the page the above php cURL script is on. (Which seems that the correct file is read by the script)

I also get error messages saying,

- `Warning: fopen(../axxxxxxx/public_html/images/new.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ayyyyyyy/public_html/test.php on line 5`
- `Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/ayyyyyyy/public_html/test.php on line 8`

The unicode charactor set displayed here (**`PNG  IHDRàw=ø IDATxÚ•yLWÇ¿3³3³ì² (VP)àUÓzDc«`**)

- `Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/ayyyyyyy/public_html/test.php on line 12`

Both sites are hosted at 000webhost.com if that matters.

***How can I download the file to the user's computer?***

Comment: The error messages are clear enough: you failed to properly open a file handle. You try to use that invalid file handle with curl/fclose, producing more warnings. Never assume success when dealing with external resources - always check for error conditions. e.g. fopen() returns boolean FALSE upon failure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (if any) is that the file you're downloading is a `PNG` file and you're trying to read it as a text file - this is the "strange code" you're seeing.

If you, before you output the file to the browser, sent the `Content-Type` header you will see the actual image:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $data;
```

By `download the file to the user's computer`, I'm assuming you mean that you want to prompt the user to download the file. To do that, set the `Content-disposition` header as an `attachment`. You can combine this with the content-type header from above too:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"some_image.png\"");
```

Comment: thanks. I'll try that. I'm giving the script many requests. (e.g. download many file types)I tried the example at php.net `read_file` function without any luck. And what about the error messages?

Comment: @Sid The error means that either the file can't be created *or*, and this is the most-likely candidate, you don't have permission to create/write-to the file. Try changing the permissions on the `/images/` folder to 0777 and see if it works.

Comment: @Sid Are you sure the path is correct? Perhaps try `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/';`? Or, if the images-folder is relative to the script you're running you could try a relative path: `$path = 'images/';`

Comment: @newfurniturey, I had the same problem with `fopen()` and using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT']` solved it. Thanks a lot for the tip!